# css: how to combine multiple stylesheets into one

Tags: css

Does anyone know on how to combine multiple stylesheets into one? For example I have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="abc.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="efg.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hij.css" />
```

in mysite.html. How can I combine the above 3 stylesheets into one?

thank you.

Answer (score 9):

You can combine your css files using [YUI Compresser](https://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/), that combines CSS and minimizes code and is good for performance.

Take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/141931/Combine-Multiple-CSS-Files-into-One-File-and-Minif), for Combining CSS files into one.

Answer (score 2):

@import is not recommended... The largest problem is that it causes files to load sequentially (one has to wait for the other) instead of in parallel (at the same time). This wastes times and round trips and makes your web page load slower.

[http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/avoid-css-import.html][1]

[1]: http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/avoid-css-import.html you can read it here...

Answer (score 1):

How about copying the content of the files into one?

Comment: I never thought answering a question with a question would work on this site.

Comment: I believe the OP wanted an automated method of combining the files.

Comment: I assume the question also means combining the rules in the CSS sheet if they are duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieive your desired results through import option......

The easier way to apply multiple files is to use the "@import" rule (browser support dependent).

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
  @import url("/css/a.css");
  @import url("/css/b.css");
  @import url("/css/c.css");
</style>
```

[you can read more about Using @import for multiple Style Sheets](http://www.free-css.com/free-css-tutorials/basic-css-tutorials/at-import.php)

Comment: Ok, I got it after reading the website link u provided. Thanks...I will try it out. :)

Comment: This still has the same performance problem as the OP's code. The goal of combining the files into a single file is to reduce the round trips to the server.

Comment: Consider the comment by John Louie above about performance issues associated with @import, and have a look at the YUI Compressor discussed below in Next Door Engineer's answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could group them with title attribute. Try to give a title attribute like 
 `title="myStyle"`

Answer (score -5):

Basically, you can keep them like that.
As long as your stylesheets don't have elements redefined from one to another, you will have no problems.
For example, if you have 2 stylesheets a.css and b.css in your htm file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="a.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="b.css" />
```

if in a.css you have

```
a{
text-decoration:none;
}
```

and in b.css

```
a{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

then the second linked stylesheet will define the text-decoration attribute of `a`

Comment: That's why they are called "Cascading" style sheets. It's by design.